# Write to Django DB from lists if criteria from database are met?

Tags: python, django, django-models

New to Django, so bear with me.  I am working on a simple link aggregator site.  I have a script that pulls links and associated info (titles, date, etc) from xml files and stores them as lists.  This is a file called `scraper.py` and is under my project app folder `news`.

`scraper.py` generates a series of lists from XML files. The scaper.py code is essentially as follows:

```
def MakeLists():
    ###lots of code to get to this point###
    ###returns the following series of lists###
    return Article_date, Article_link, Article_vote, Article_title, Article_publisher
```

These outputs correspond to my Django `models.py` file, which is as follows:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    publisher = models.URLField()
    link = models.URLField()
    date = models.DateField()
    pull_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

And here is the view that makes my home page, with my latest attempt at getting the new scraped data into my db (data is gathered in `MakeLists()`):

```
class ArticleList(ListView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'Articles'
    pull_date = Article.objects.aggregate(Max('pull_date'))

    def get_new_db_stuff(self):
        check_time = datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(hours=4)
        if pull_date > check_time: #i.e., more than 4 hours ago
            Article_date, Article_link, Article_vote, Article_title, Article_publisher = MakeLists()

            for i in range(0, len(Article_link)):
                if Article.object.filter(link=Article_link[i]).exists()==False:
                    a = Article(link=Article_link[i], date=Article_date[i], vote=Article_vote[i],
                                title=Article_title[i], publisher = Article_publisher[i])
                a.save()
```

The issue is that it just doesn't seem to be doing anything... nothing is being written to DB.  There aren't an errors popping up when I runserver or when I click on pages.

Questions:
1. How do I check if anything is being done?  i.e., figure out if variables are being created etc.?
2. My thought is that I am botching the query, but how can I troubleshoot that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is the wrong place to implement this type of solution.  It is better done by putting code all in a separate file and then placing that in a folder structure that is:

   app_name>management>commands>file_name.py
2. By putting it in this structure, it can either be ran from the `manage.py shell` or can be set up as a chron job (better).
3. For the comparison

   if Article.objects.filter(link=Article_link[i]).exists() == False:

works just fine.